# Git deletes files between branchs

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Suppose:

- I have a master branch
- From it I created a developer branch
- I made several changes (including new files, for example, files A and B)
- There was an error in production and I had to fix it
- I created a new bugfix branch from the master
- I changed some files. Problem solved.
- I went back to the master branch, and made a merge with the bugfix (from bugfix to master)
- I returned to the developer branch and merge to make a bugfix (or master). In doing so, my files A and B were excluded.

Why does this happen?

Note. I'm using SourceTree and not changed any default git configuration.

Comment: Did you commit the changes in step 3? What commands did you run at each step? This is too vague to provide an answer.

Comment: Yes. I commits in all cases.
I tried to simplify the case in these steps, but the project already has many other commits and merges. The other times I did merge from bugfix to developer, this problem did not happen.
Almost did not use commands (with the exception of 'git checkout branchname'). The operations were performed in SourceTree.

Comment: So in your last two steps, you merged 'bugfix' into 'master', and then merged 'bugfix' into 'develop'?  Or merged 'develop' into something else?

Comment: In the penultimate step I merged 'bugfix' into 'master'. In the last step I merged 'bugfix' into 'Develop'. It is marking the files included in developer for deletion.
I also tried the merged 'master' into 'Develop', but the problem also happened.